# Why this sitecore query is not returning any items despite the fact that item with specified field value exists?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm trying to query one item's descendants using following query :

[image]

And not getting any items despite the fact that item with specified field value exists?

This query in query analyzer for some reason works:

```
select * from /sitecore/content/itema/News/descendant::*[@NewsId='235271']
```

Any help in correcting my code to get back item I'm searching for?

```
string sitecoreQuery = "descendant::*[@NewsId='" + item.Id.ToString() + "']";
Item[] newsItems = parent.Axes.SelectItems(sitecoreQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on your comment:

The query looks ok, but you could also try using the shortcut for descendants: `//*`. I have just tested this locally and it returned me expected items.

```
string sitecoreQuery = "//*[@NewsId='" + item.Id.ToString() + "']";
Item[] newsItems = parent.Axes.SelectItems(sitecoreQuery);
```

Also double check that `item.Id.ToString()` is returning the Id you are expecting.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Richard, sorry I forgot to mention that newsId is not a guid but just a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
Item[] newsItems = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(string.Format("/sitecore/content/itema/News//*[@NewsId='{0}']", NewsId));
```

That should get you the filtered items